# Nginx 502 Bad Gateway and [error] 23645#0

Tags: nginx

I've just installed Nginx on Ubuntu 14.04. I'd like to host multiple applications on this server. Currently I have two server blocks: `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` and `/etc/nginx/sites-available/test`. Both are symlinked to `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`. I'd like `/etc/nginx/sites-available/test` to serve to a subdomain I've set up and `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` to serve to all other requests made to port 80. However, I get a 502 Bad Gateway error page and `[error] 23645#0: *1 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream` in the error log. The only way I can get `/etc/nginx/sites-available/test` to serve is to set the IP address explicitly in the listen directive. But in that case, all requests made to port 80 are served `/etc/nginx/sites-available/test`. It seems like the `server_name` directive is being ignored.

Here are both server blocks:

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/default`

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /usr/share/nginx/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name localhost;
```

`/etc/nginx/sites-available/test`

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/test/html;
        index index.html index.htm;

        server_name subdomain.domain.com;
```

Comment: have You solve Your issue?